# The difference between a-b>0 and a>b

Tags: c

IN my class, writing C code, I understand a-b may trigger a overflow, messing things up. But
How computer know a>b without minus?

Thanks!

Comment: it can compare binary presentation without any arithmetical operations

Comment: Can you tell me whether or not 12 is larger than 9 without performing a subtraction?

Comment: So, can you do it or not? If you can do it, so can a computer.

Comment: [How does the computer determine whether a number is smaller or greater than another?](http://cs.stackexchange.com/a/7084)

Comment: If it's implemented as a subtraction at some level (which is likely), it wouldn't then compare the result with zero again (how? by subtracting again - ad infinitum?) but with some different outputs of the subtractor.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, a better question is, can **a computer** tell? My experience with assembly says they generally can't.

Comment: @TomZych Of course they can. It's trivially easy to write an algorithm to compare numbers without subtraction.

Comment: @harold To compare, the arithmetic result of the comparison, at the machine code level, is usually not checked, but just the process flags like "overflow,, is-zero, carry and sign".

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: well, yes, good point. I was thinking more in terms of how they actually do it, rather than all the ways they theoretically could do it.

Comment: @chux yea that's what I said .. without the details

Comment: Many CPUs have distinct SUB (subtract) and CMP (compare) instructions.

Comment: Also take compiler optimizations into account. A compiler may use the undefined behaviour triggered by `a-b` in case of an overflow; for `a>b`, it mustn't.

Comment: @KeithThompson sure, but `cmp` usually works by subtracting anyway and that brings us back to more confusion for OP.

Answer (score 0):

Let's look at the following two binary numbers:

```
101 (5)
100 (4)
```

All the computer has to do is go down the bits, starting from the leading digit. So the computer first compares the 4s place. They match. Next it checks the 2s place. Again, they match. Lastly, it compares the 1s place. The first number has a 1 and the second has a 0, so you know the first number (5) is greater than the second (4).

I made a ton of generalizations here, but if you understand how logic gates work (specifically XNOR gates), you can expand upon this.

Comment: You make that sound awfully serial

Comment: if you could explain how to use XNOR ,that would be great. I know the definition of XNOR

Comment: @harold process may seem rather serial, but you can do this in a parallel fashion.

Comment: @user3495562 check out this image: http://www.expertsmind.com/CMSImages/422_4bit-comparator.png. The diagram depicts a 4-bit digital comparator.